# Cannot find origin object in Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just inherited a Rails app for a new gig.  Thee code is insane and heavily buried in gem logic so VERY difficult and un-rails-like to navigate.  I am having a terrible time tracking down the following logic.

```
    @navigator ||= BitPlayer::Navigator.new(current_participant)
```

I have searched everywhere (in app as well as gem dirs) for a BitPlayer class/object as well as Navigator and cannot find a thing.  I am thinking I don't understand the fundamental composition of the line.

Can someone point me in the right direction where to look for this?  I desperately need to find that "Navigator.new" method!

Comment: It isn't in the `bit_player` gem? I think it is here isn;t it? https://github.com/NU-CBITS/bit_player/blob/master/app/models/bit_player/navigator.rb

Comment: Well, now, I have NO idea how search did not find this method.  Thank you!

Comment: I find it is easier to search the github repos then open up the gem and search it.

Answer (score 6):

You could try [`Method#source_location`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-source_location). For example:

```
Nokogiri::HTML.method(:fragment).source_location
# ["/Users/mu/.../gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/lib/nokogiri/html.rb", 29]
```

And then looking line 29 of the file we see:

```
def fragment string, encoding = nil
```

So start with:

```
BitPlayer::Navigator.method(:initialize).source_location
```