# Ruby on Rails help on how to find from where a method comes from

Tags: ruby-on-rails

RoR noob here.

I need to decorate some controllers, helpers, models etc from Solidus. Solidus is divided in solidus_core, solidus_backend, solidus_frontend, solidus_api... finding what I need is a pain in the ass. I basically open the one that seems the most obvious for what I'm looking for but often I end up opening all of them and doing a global search. Is there an easier way?

Also when I'm looking at a view, sometimes I see something that looks like a method call. How can I know if it comes from a helper or the controller? How can I know if it comes instead from a gem? Or from another related package that is part of a gem?

I find it so confusing, I never know where things are and where to look for them. Am I missing something?

Comment: Related: [**Cannot find origin object in Rails project**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63974323/479863).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the duck typed nature of Ruby, and the heavy use of meta programming in rails, this type of problem is not easily solved.

Two pieces of advice:

1. Use an IDE such as RubyMine or VS Code to *jump to declaration* - you can control click to jump to the definition of methods. This doesn't always work, but it does most of the time, as long as the method has a unique name.
2. Use an IDE that has good search functionality. I personally use VIM because I can easily extend the search component to use command line linux, making it very fast to scan very large projects quickly.